# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Installation not loading

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, 18.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a dell optiplex 3050 micro for testing.

After booting from USB I choose English and select "Install".
A lot of Text comes to the screen seemingly loading components. Unfortunately it is to fast for me to read.

A Ubuntu 18.04 loading screen will appear for a few seconds. Afterwards it again loads some stuff. At some point the monitor is black with an orange marker on the top left corner.
The marker blinks (similar to dos or cmd).

The "commandline interface" does not have any text on it and seemingly doesn't react to keyboard entries.

I tried to let it load for quite some time without any result. Is it trying to load something? How can I get ubuntu server installed?

best regards,

Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to expand on Julian's answer and add some more troubleshooting problems I had. I was setting up a Windows 10-Ubuntu 18.04 dual-boot on a refurbished laptop.

1. First update laptop bios if needed. Just google "$my_laptop_model bios update" and you should find an official utility to update.
2. Check if Windows is booted in Legacy BIOS or UEFI mode. Hit `Win+R` and run `msinfo32.exe`. Under "System Summary" there will be a "BIOS mode" which should be `UEFI`.
3. If BIOS mode is `Legacy` then you need to convert to UEFI with MBR2GPT.EXE (its on all Windows 10 version 1703 or later PC's). I re-merged my Ubuntu partition into the Windows parition, then ran `mbr2gpt /convert /allowfullOS`.
4. Once this is complete open your bios (should do this by hitting f12 during boot sequence). Go to the BOOT tab and ensure that BIOS is booting into UEFI only, not "legacy", "both", or "uefi first".
5. Download ubuntu ISO and mount to a FAT32 formatted USB drive using unetbootin
6. Reboot and change boot order (f2 or f8 during startup) to load the USB first. Boot into the usb, select "Install Ubuntu", shrink the main Windows Partition and format to ext4 with a `/` mount point. Maybe add a swap partition. Install Ubuntu on the new parition.
7. Install should succeed. If Ubuntu does not appear in the boot menu during next startup, boot into the USB and select "Try Ubuntu". Open a terminal and install and run boot-repair

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
   `sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
8. Ubuntu should work!

I had a ton of errors install 18, that did not appear if I formatted my usb with Ubuntu 16. Stuff like

```
SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x2f12cf1e
[1889.190202] blk_update_request: I/O error, devloop0, sector 1542506
[1889.190271] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [2f12cf1e]
[1889.190271] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 2f12cf1e, size 697d
```

I read an answer somewhere that switching out the USB with another can solve this problem, but I didn't have any others. I just kept reformatting and mounting the Ubuntu 18 installation media on the same USB. Each time installation would fail at a different place. Eventually (over a day) it succeeded in entirety and the installation has been working well. GLHF

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

The Installer/USB drive has to be booted in UEFI mode...

best regads,

Julian